# putting UI animations on the main thread?

Tags: ios, swift

- I was wondering if it was a good practice of putting UI animations on
  the main thread?

  for example whenever you need to `reloadData()` on a tableView you should do it on the main thread. So I figured if I need to reload my tableView but I want to do some light animations along to reflect the changes like animating opacity and frame of the tableView It must not be bad to put those animations on the main thread as well?

Comment: Any operation that affects the UI needs to be on the main queue.  You don't need to dispatch on to the main queue if you are already on the main queue; e.g. If you reload a table view in a button tap handler, there is no need to dispatch because you are already on the main queue.  If you are reloading in a network fetch completion handler you are probably not on the main queue so you need to dispatch.

Comment: Your app will helpfully crash should you ever try to run your UIKit animations anywhere but on the main thread :)

Comment: @Gamma I'm animating the opacity of a tableView inside geocoder.geocodeAddressString callback and I didn't put it on the main queue it works and the app doesn't crash

Comment: @lychee then it would appear your `geocoder.geocodeAddressString callback` is being executed on the main thread. (Just because code is in a callback closure doesn't mean that it will be automatically dispatched to a new thread).